# confused sending json as a parameter

Tags: java, json, http-post

I've the below java program that prints a json string.

```
System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectsToSerialise));
```

I tried to find the type of `objectsToSerialise` with the below line of code.

```
    System.out.println(objectsToSerialise.getClass().getTypeName());
```

this returned `java.util.ArrayList`

the output that I get is as below.

```
[ {
  "EntityLabels" : [ {
    "StartToken" : 8,
    "EntityType" : "Personname",
    "EndToken" : 16
  }, {
    "StartToken" : 24,
    "EntityType" : "Amount::Spent",
    "EndToken" : 31
  } ],
  "ExampleText" : "What is Frede's limit? ",
  "SelectedIntentName" : "GiftLimit"
} ]
```

And I'm trying to post the same to my API . And the code is as below.

And `luisUrl ="https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"`

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(luisUrl + "/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/" + appId + "/examples?");
httpPost.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subsriptionId);
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(objectsToSerialise.toString());
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        /* Debug Info */
System.out.println("---------------Start2----------------");
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(responseString);
System.out.println("---------------End----------------");
        /*End Debug Info*/
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201) {
        success = true;
        System.out.println("Success");
} else {
        System.out.println("Block");
        success = false;
}
```

And this is always printing `else` content. i.e. `Block`. I thought this might be an issue with my calling and tried the same in `Postman`. with the below details.

**URL:**https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/{appId}/examples?

**Method:** post

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type:application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:{mySubscriptionKey}
```

**Body:**raw->JSON
**Content:**

```
[ {
  "EntityLabels" : [ {
    "StartToken" : 8,
    "EntityType" : "Personname",
    "EndToken" : 16
  }, {
    "StartToken" : 24,
    "EntityType" : "Amount::Spent",
    "EndToken" : 31
  } ],
  "ExampleText" : "What is Frede's limit? ",
  "SelectedIntentName" : "GiftLimit"
} ]
```

To my surprise, when I post this, it is returning me `201`, where as my Java code is returning me `400`.

This is very confusing. Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectsToSerialize` seems to be an `ArrayList`, but in your code you construct request body with `new StringEntity(objectsToSerialise.toString());`. That is, you don't convert your `ArrayList` to JSON, but instead you just get its string representation which is not a JSON usually.

Try changing

```
new StringEntity(objectsToSerialise.toString());
```

to

```
new StringEntity(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectsToSerialise));
```